# Should I connect to a redis cluster based only on the masters?

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am using `stachexchange.redis` library to connect to a redis cluster. The cluster has 3 masters and 4 slaves.

In my connection using the multiplexer which servers should I use in the connection string? only one of the masters or all of the servers?

Currently using:

`ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("master1, master2, master3")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shouldn't really matter. When talking to a cluster, it will use `CLUSTER NODES` or `CLUSTER SLOTS` to discover the topology.

Comment: if i change the connection string to a single server, and that server goes down, will it still be able to determine the rest of the topology?

Comment: No it won't, you should indicate more servers to provide High-Availability. It doesn't matter if they are master or slave.